# Negative square root

Tags: c++, math, sqrt

How do you take the square root of a negative number in C++?
I know it should return a real and a complex part, I get a NaN?
How do I take the real part?

Comment: so many problems for developers, physicists because of wrong axiomatics in multiplication...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <complex>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> two_i = std::sqrt(std::complex<double>(-4));
}
```

or just

```
std::complex<double> sqrt_minus_x(0, std::sqrt(std::abs(x)));
```

Answer (score 5):

`sqrt(-x)` where x is a positive number is simply `0 + sqrt(x)*i`. The real part is just 0.

In general, the real part is `x > 0 ? sqrt(x) : 0` and the imaginary part is `x < 0 ? sqrt(x) : 0`.

Answer (score 3):

If what you call a negative number is a real, then the real part of its square root should just be `0`?

Comment: +1; I was so excited to post this answer, but it was already here!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
double negativeNumber = -321;
std::complex<double> number( negativeNumber, 0 );
std::complex<double> result = sqrt( number );
double realpart = result.real();
```