# Why am I getting NaN when I should be getting a double?

Tags: c++

My problem is somewhere in the definition of `first_x` and `second_x`. When I call the `quad_eq` function, I get a -nan(ind) return based on the code below. If I change the `.pushback()` method parameter to be a literal integer, I get that integer returned instead of NaN. This leads me to believe that the problem is with my calculation/definition of `first_x` and `second_x`. Maybe there is some trick to C++ that I am not seeing or understanding. Can anyone see what my problem is? (If this helps I am working out of Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Principles and Practice Using C++ where he gives me the std_lib_facilities.h file to use as I do not understand headers yet)

```
vector<double>quad_eq(double a, double b, double c) {
    vector<double>answers;
    double first_x = (-b + sqrt((b * 2) - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
    double second_x = (-b - sqrt((b * 2) - (4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
    answers.push_back(first_x);
    answers.push_back(second_x);
    return answers;
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `b * b` instead of `b * 2`.

Comment: A NaN is a perfectly legitimate content for a double. Especially if you aren't careful with the values you feed into certain operations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Squareroot returning not a number in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950603/squareroot-returning-not-a-number-in-c)

Comment: I have fixed the B * B problem but that has not solved my problem. I am putting in perfectly legitimate and already solved quadratic inputs and still getting back NaN. My problem has to be with my definition/parenthesis.

Comment: Show the values of a, b,c.

Comment: What legitimate inputs are you putting in exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the input, you are taking the square root of negative numbers, so you get NaN (which is, in fact, a double) out of that, and any other operations propagate that.

Sidenote: the code you show doesn't compile as-is, because it is missing `#include <vector>` and `using namespace std;`. The latter is also usually [frowned upon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: My code is compiling. I have a header included made by the author of this book that deals with that even though I do not understand it yet. My problem is something with my calculation. I'm thinking it is maybe my parenthesis at this point. I am putting in perfectly legitimate quadratic formula inputs and they are still coming out as NaN even though on paper they come out how they should.

Comment: @ObamaBinTrappin `b * b` is not the same as `b * 2`.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I fixed that but it has not solved the NaN problem.

Comment: If you call `quad_eq( 1, 2, 3 )` then `b * 2 - (4 * a * c )` equals -8, and `sqrt(-8)` in c++ returns a double, not a complex number, and so it chooses to return NaN here because it cannot possibly express the result in a double. What do you expect to happen instead? You don't specify that.. Do you need a complex number? (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042760/negative-square-root for instance)